# Is providing explicitly the context bound possible in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz

In the following code:

```
   def sum[A: Monoid](xs: List[A]): A = {
     val m = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
     xs.foldLeft(m.mzero)(m.mappend)
   }
```

If I already have in my scope a `Monoid[Int]` that has `mappend = _ + _`, can I call my function with an explicit `Monoid[Int]` which has a different behavior? Or the only solution is to use a more verbose syntax with a second argument `implicit monoid: Monoid[Int]`?

---

The code exemple comes from this Scalaz tutorial: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/sum+function.html

At the end the author shows an exemple of providing explicitly the Monoid, but he didn't use context bounds:

```
scala> val multiMonoid: Monoid[Int] = new Monoid[Int] {
         def mappend(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
         def mzero: Int = 1
       }
multiMonoid: Monoid[Int] = $anon$1@48655fb6

scala> sum(List(1, 2, 3, 4))(multiMonoid)
res14: Int = 24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context bounds are nothing more than syntactic sugar.
The following:

```
def sum[A: Monoid](xs: List[A])
```

is extactly the same as:

```
def sum[A](xs: List[A])(implicit evidence: Monoid[A])
```

This means that regardless of the way you defined your `sum` method (either with a context bound or with an implicit parameter), you can explicitly pass the implicit parameter as in `sum(List(1, 2, 3, 4))(multiMonoid)`